# Powershell syntax , using zip compression and global variables?

Tags: powershell, compression, zip, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I was playing around with the system zip compression, before we always used 7zip and I want to be more agile with all our scripts.

I found this :

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\folder1"
$destinationZip = "c:\zipped.zip" 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceFolder, $destinationZip)
```

this works fine! But,

as soon as i create a function out of this and put in global variables i am not able to run the script.

```
$dest = "C:\_archive\ImportJournals\ImportJournals.zip"

$source = "C:\_archive\ImportJournals\temp\"



function ZipFiles ([string]$destination, [string]$sourcedir )
{
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $destination) 
}

ZipFiles ( $dest, $source )
```

I get an `Error : "The path if not of an legal form."`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for calling a Powershell function would be:

```
ZipFiles $dest  $source
```